# Javascript Closure/Event Handling Nightmare

Tags: javascript, events, maps, closures, ovi

I am using the ovi maps API and I have a polyline with an event handler. The event handler  looks like the following

```
 SomeClass = Base.extend({
    _clickFunction: function(evt) {
          alert(this.someBaseClassMethod() + 'x: ' + evt.targetX+ 'y:'+ evt.targetY);
    },
    go: function(){
          myClickableThing.addListener('click', this._clickFunction.bind(this));
    }
   }
```

The first time I click my thing I get X and Y that are correct for the pixel position of the cursor and an accurate timestamp. For every subsequent click on the same polyLine I get the exact same X,Y,and Timestamp. Does anyone have any thoughts or a workaround?

Comment: what does this line do this._clickFunction.bind(this)? never seen this before..

Comment: Why do you need to bind `this._clickFunction.bind(this));`? It doesn't look like the function is using the `this` object, so you should be able to just use `this._clickFunction`.

Comment: assuming your _clickFunction is private to this object.. shouldnt you just give a reference to that function as the eventHandler. i.e myClickableThing.addListener('click', _clickFunction);

Comment: This particular app is using Base.js. I think that is used to bind a class level function as a contextual reference to containing this object/function so you can use this in _clickFunction to refer to its containing class. Basically so this mimicks what this would do in java

Comment: I edited it to more accurately reflect what I'm looking at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thanks for all those that answered. I did manage to solve this problem although I can't tell you why it didn't work in the first place(If anyone regularly fishes around in the ECMAscript standard please feel free to contact me). The issue was definitely `this._clickFunction.bind(this))`. For what ever reason this creates a closure that retains the `evt` object. The solution(as some of you suggested in the comments) was simply to work around that line by setting the function up in the constructor.

Original:

```
   SomeClass = Base.extend({
    _clickFunction: function(evt) {
          alert(this.someBaseClassMethod() + 'x: ' + evt.targetX+ 'y:'+ evt.targetY);
    },
    go: function(){
          myClickableThing.addListener('click', this._clickFunction.bind(this));
    }
   }
```

Fixed Version:

```
  SomeClass = Base.extend({
    _clickFunction:null,
    constructor: function(){
      this._clickFunction = function(evt) {
          alert(this.someBaseClassMethod() + 'x: ' + evt.targetX+ 'y:'+ evt.targetY);
      }
    },
    go: function(){
          myClickableThing.addListener('click', this._clickFunction);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways I am not sure of the OVImap API but I am guessing it will pass its own event object to you to the handler method. see if that gives you the right values.

your listener function will be something like:

```
myClickableThing.addListener('click', function(event){this._clickFunction(event)});
```

Hope this helps.

On a side note wEll we ran into a similar issue on google maps and one particular browser where in the evt variable was not scoped correctly or something of that sort.

I am not sure if that is your problem.